# I want to return id from a json list.But it gave a error

Tags: asp.net, json, moodle

***Error:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'exception', line 1, position 13***

MY code:

```
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.QueryString.Add("wstoken", "49345fa96c58118326b874bxxxxxx");
                wc.QueryString.Add("wsfunction", "core_user_create_users");
                wc.QueryString.Add("moodlewsrestformat", "json");
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][username]", member.uname);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][auth]", "manual");
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][password]", member.password);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][firstname]", member.fname);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][lastname]", member.lname);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][email]", member.email);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][timezone]", member.timezone);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][description]", member.tag);//tag for group name
                var response_data = wc.UploadValues(URI, "POST", wc.QueryString);

                var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response_data);
                var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(response);
                foreach (var a in k)
                {
                    id = (a["id"]);
                }
                return id;

            }
```

***I want to return id from below output:***

```
[{\"id\":38,\"username\":\"newuser30\"}]
```

Comment: Hi Tereen, can you take a look at my answer and see if it helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it just worked for me:

```
string json = "[{\"id\":38,\"username\":\"newuser30\"}]";
dynamic [] stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic []>(json);

var id = stuff[0].id;
```